# presentedViewController Changes KVO

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to listen to changes for the presentedViewController, but it doesn't look like that property is KVO compliant (or at least I'm not able to get changes from it).  Is there a way in UIViewController to listen to changes when a UIViewController is actively presented?

Comment: It feels like custom containment is the way to go.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

`presentedViewController` doesn't appear to be KVO-compliant, but it is possible to be notified of changes by overriding the relevant presentation/dismissal methods of `UIViewController`:

```
override func presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    // will present view controller
    super.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
}

override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)
    // did dismiss view controller
}
```

Swift 4:

```swift
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        observation = observe(\.presentationController, options: [.old, .new]) { _, change in
            print("presentationController changed")
            if let vc = change.newValue as? UIPresentationController {
                print("presentedViewController: \(vc.presentedViewController.presentedViewController)")
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        observation?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Please note that observing `presentationController` with KVO does not have official Apple documentation; therefore, it may be removed in the future.